# pg_restore: creating MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA taking long time

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.5.3. When I restoring the database, and it creating MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA, it takes me a long time, 3 hrs more. Is this really normal for postgresql?

```
pg_restore: creating MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA "public.mydata"
```

still on process. and my database.backup is 15gb sized

Comment: How long did the initial (original) creation of the MVIEW take?

Comment: 3hrs can be super fast or super slow. It depends on the definition of the MATERIALIZED VIEW.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the view definition, the current table statistics and the data present.

You could examine the query plan for query defining the materialized view with `EXPLAIN` and see if there are any problems with the plan.

If it is a complicated query, maybe the problem is that autoanalyze didn't have time yet to calculate table statistics.

You can interrupt the statement with `pg_cancel_backend()` and recreate the materialized view later, perhaps after an `ANALYZE`, if it helps you to bring the rest of the database up quickly.